# XML operations in memory

Tags: java, xml, memory

I want to process in memory to show a file with an invoice XML to users. I will generate XSLT from this XML file (embedded in XSLT as base64). With this XSLT, I will show HTML production to the user. After the user views it, it will be removed from memory.

What is the best way to do this and how to do it?

Does it make sense to do these operations in memory for a web application with many users? If not, I am open to another method suggestion, but I still wonder how to do these operations in memory with XML.

Comment: I doubt you'll be generating dynamic XSLT. Much more likely the XSLT will be static, and that you will merge some dynamic XML with the static XSLT to create HTML

Comment: Have you considered using [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/index.html) instead of XSLT? Much simpler to understand, and less verbose to maintain

Comment: For a "web application with many users", if the same XSLT stylesheet is being used again and again, then it's important to compile it once at start-of-day and reuse the compiled version. You approach doesn't seem to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have an XML document containing some data alongside a BASE64 encoded XSLT which should be used to format that data.

Then this should do the job:

```
@Test
byte [] test() throws Exception {
    byte[] incoming = ...; // Your XML document
    
    Document doc;
    try(ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(incoming)) {
        doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
    }
    
    String encodedXslt = doc....getTextContent(); // Somehow fetch the encoded XSLT from the DOM.
    byte[] xslt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedXslt);
    
    Templates templates;
    try(ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xslt)) {
        templates = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTemplates(new StreamSource(is));
    }
    
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        templates.newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
        return os.toByteArray(); // The HTML document
    }
}
```

Completely in memory, but be aware that someone may use the XSLT to call Java code from your application.

Comment: I didn't understand this part:"Completely in memory, but be aware that someone may use the XSLT to call Java code from your application"

Comment: 1. The above function happens completely in memory. 2. It's possible to execute Java code from inside an XSLT stylesheet. If the stylesheet comes from outside of your application you'll have to be aware, that someone may have bad intentions.